# Using Event Delegation, why is the eventPhase 0, meaning None?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-delegation

I tried out event delegation and checked the `eventPhase` of the event object.  Surprisingly, it showed `0` meaning `Event.NONE` explained as "No event is being processed at this time" as defined on [Mozilla's eventPhase description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase).

This is true in the current Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, while IE 11 actually reported a `3` for `Event.BUBBLING_PHASE`.

You can try out [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0qu1dm9/) if you want, but it is optional.

Is there a reason for it to be `0`?  Is `0` actually more correct (for a reason), or is `3` actually the correct one?

Comment: That's an artifact of the "live console" feature of these browsers. When you log a complete object, the logged representation will be updated when you expand it, and by that time the event has been processed and `eventPhase` is `0`. Logging `ev.eventPhase` doesn't have this problem and logs `3` ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0qu1dm9/5/)).

Comment: so I supposed these browsers could have saved a shallow copy of the object for debugging accuracy? Interesting... so it seems that IE 11 actually does that, or that it doesn't clear up the `eventPhase`

Answer (score -1):

According to https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-the-event-object,

> The `currentTarget` property changes as the event flows through the different event listeners. And it's also set to `null` when the event is finished dispatching.